# Inverse pair equidistant from 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Say you pick a number $x$, like $\frac 43$.  Its inverse is of course $\frac 34$.  $x$ is a distance of $\frac 13$ away from 1, and its inverse is a distance of $\frac 14$ away from 1.  Is there any number $x$ that is a distance $d$ away from 1, whose inverse $\frac 1x$ is also a distance $d$ away from 1?  I came up with the following equation and found the solution $x = 1$, but I was hoping there was another solution.

$x - 1 = 1 - \frac 1x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your equation only has the solution $x=1$ but that doesn't mean that the only solutions to the problem are solutions to said equation. You can easily check that -1 also satisfies your problem. Maybe consider the following equation, since you're measuring distance:
\begin{equation*}
|x-1| = \left|1-\frac{1}{x}\right|.
\end{equation*}

Edit in response to OPs comment: You can consider all possible cases. First rewrite the equation to
\begin{equation*}
|x-1| = \left|1-\frac{1}{x}\right| \iff 
|x-1| = \left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right|.
\end{equation*}
Case 1: $x>1.$ Then
\begin{equation*}
|x-1| = x-1 = 1-\frac{1}{x} = \left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right| \iff x+\frac{1}{x}=2.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, there is no real solution for $x>1$.

We've already considered the case $x=1$. So let's consider $0<x<1$. Then
\begin{equation*}
|x-1| = 1-x = \frac{1}{x}-1 = \left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right| \iff x+\frac{1}{x}=2,
\end{equation*}
but we're only considering $0<x<1$, so the equation has no solution for $0<x<1$.

We're not going to consider the case $x=0$. So let's consider $-1<x<0$. Then
\begin{equation*}
|x-1| = 1-x = 1-\frac{1}{x} = \left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right| \iff x-\frac{1}{x} = 0,
\end{equation*}
which has no solution for $0<x<1$.

We've alread covered the case $x=-1$, so let's consider $x<-1$ as our last case. Then
\begin{equation*}
|x-1| = 1-x = 1-\frac{1}{x} = \left|\frac{1}{x}-1\right| \iff x-\frac{1}{x} = 0,
\end{equation*}
which, again, has no solution. So, yes, $\pm 1$ are the only real solutions to your problem.

Comment: Is that the only other solution?

Comment: You could have $i$. Or any other (imaginary) unit.

Comment: True, I was considering real numbers. $i$ and $-i$ would work, among other complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks so much for a detailed and thought-out response!

Answer (score 0):

From
$|x-1| 
= \left|1-\frac{1}{x}\right|.
$,
squaring both sides,
$x^2-2x+1
=1/x^2-2/x+1
$
or
$x^2-1/x^2-2x+2/x
=0
$
or
$2(x-1/x)
=x^2-1/x^2
=(x-1/x)(x+1/x)
$.

If
$x=1/x$,
then $x = \pm 1$.
These both satisfy
$|x-1| 
= \left|1-\frac{1}{x}\right|
$.

If
$x\ne 1/x$,
then $x +1/x=2$.
THis implies that
$x > 0$.
Therefore
$0
=x -2+1/x
=(\sqrt{x}-\frac1{\sqrt{x}})^2
$
so
$\sqrt{x}
=\frac1{\sqrt{x}}
$
so $x = 1$.